# WordPress French characters are not showing correctly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I downloaded my production server's WordPress solution to localhost one. its french based web site. Now it shows me abnormal characters. Please help me to resolve this.

**wp-config.php**

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aBmx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the encoding rule to utf8 in your database. This can easily be done with phpMyAdmin for example. If this does not solve your issue, add encoding attribute to your Html tag.

If you also have bad text in your post content, then either the stored data is wrongly encoded or the database connection is converting it.

If your WordPress config has standard settings like `define('DB_CHARSET','utf8')` then the latter is less likely, but check the WordPress documentation on character sets and collation.

You say you "migrated" your site. If that involved SQL dumps then you may have broken your UTF-8 encoding at the database level.